# How to fill a List with entries from a Map in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to do the equivalent of this Python code in Dart. Possibly as a one liner I could use in a return statement.

```
m = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
l = [1, 3]
[m[index] for index in l]
```

this results in a new list like this ['a', 'c']

A long version of this in Dart would be this.

```
List<String> r = [];
for (var key in l) {
  r.add(m[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
void main() {
  final m = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'};
  final l = [1, 3, 4];

  List<String> r1 = m.entries.where((e) => l.contains(e.key)).map((e) => e.value).toList();
  List<String> r2 = l.where((k) => m.containsKey(k)).map((k) => m[k]).toList();
  print(r1); // [a, c]
  print(r2); // [a, c]
}
```

**Update 1:** Added another example (r2) which iterate over the list instead.

**Update 2:** Added check to second solution so it only map keys there are in the map.

Comment: yes that looks good, but is there also a oneliner for the other way round. Right now this goes through every entry in the map and searched it in the list. Sine my map will be huge and the list short it makes more sense iterating over the list and picking the map values.

Comment: Sure, I will look into that. Give me 5 minutes. :)

Comment: Second solution throws error. Imagine m does not include k as a key.

Comment: Well, then we just add a where. Try now. :)